# I made a model using Jupyter Notebook and then I am trying to deploy the model using streamlit but it is showing ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter, streamlit

I created a model and deployed using streamlit. I am running in a virtual environement and inspite of running pip install streamlit it is still not working. The following error is shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC9pS.png)

The error that is shown is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Machine Learning\sms-spam-classifier\venv\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "d:\machine learning\sms-spam-classifier\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from streamlit.delta_generator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator
  File "d:\machine learning\sms-spam-classifier\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\delta_generator.py", line 90, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.arrow_altair import ArrowAltairMixin
  File "d:\machine learning\sms-spam-classifier\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow_altair.py", line 35, in <module>
    from altair.vegalite.v4.api import Chart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'altair.vegalite.v4'
PS D:\Machine Learning\sms-spam-classifier>
```

Comment: As you're using a flavour of Python3, do you need to use pip3 install streamlit? We don't know anything about the configuration of your system form what you have provided but this could help.

Comment: So instead of pip install i should use pip3 install streamlit?

Comment: It looks like it to me, yes. But as someone else said, seems you need altair as well...

Comment: i have installed altair and when i do pip show altair its showing me the version i am using, i also tried pip install --upgrade altair
 but it is not working still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
pip install altair
```

Comment: Yes i tried that

Answer (score 1):

pip install altair
was not working for me. I used:

```
pip install altair==4
```

See: [Discussion](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-altair-vegalite-v4/42921)